# Let $T: R_3 \to R_3$ be the transformation that reflects vector $x=(x_1, x_2, x_3)$ through the plane $x_3=0$ onto $T(x) = (x_1, x_2, -x_3)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, linear-transformations

Let $T: R_3 \to R_3$ be the transformation that reflects vector $x=(x_1, x_2, x_3)$ through the plane $x_3=0$ onto $T(x) = (x_1, x_2, -x_3).$

I am trying to find if $T$ is a linear transformation and if not why.

I have no idea how to start this problem. Can anyone give me some kind of direction and help me figure out this problem step by step? I have been working on figuring out how to answer linear transformation problems, but the way this one is worded just throws me off. Thanks!

So far I have answered:

Let $R_2$ to $R_3$ be the transformation defined by $T(x_1, x_2) = (2x_1-3x_2, x_1+4, 5x_2)$
I calculated that the above was not a linear transformation because $T(u+v) = T(u) + T(v)$ was not satisfied. Hopefully I am on the right track here with that conclusion. So help me out!!

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Sorry, I edited it and added the actual question part. I just wanted to make sure I included the important parts and forgot :(

Comment: Well it gives you the prescription for $T$: $$T(x_1, x_2, x_3) = (x_1, x_2, -x_3)$$ so you just need to check whether $T(\mathbf x+\lambda \mathbf y) = T(\mathbf x) + \lambda T(\mathbf y)$ for all $\mathbf x, \mathbf y$ and $\lambda$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll begin the proof for you:

Let $a = (a_1, a_2, a_3), b=(b_1, b_2, b_3)\in\Bbb R^3$ and $\lambda \in\Bbb R$.  Then

$$\begin{align}T[a+\lambda b] &= T(a_1+\lambda b_1, a_2+\lambda b_2, a_3+\lambda b_3) \\ &= (a_1+\lambda b_1, a_2+\lambda b_2, -(a_3+\lambda b_3)) \\ &\qquad\vdots \\ &\stackrel{?}=T(a)+\lambda T(b)\end{align}$$

See if you can get to that last step or not and you'll be done.

Comment: i do not know all of those symbols. What is λ?

Comment: An arbitrary real number.  That's what $\in \Bbb R$ means: "is an element of $\Bbb R$ (the real numbers)".  If Greek symbols throw you, you can use any other symbol you like: $c$, $k$, $a$, $\alpha$, etc.

Comment: Thank you I was used to c, but I understand now. Let me try to draw it out and come back with any questions.

Comment: Hey was I right about the second part of my question? Because if I was I know I am at least doing these right and then I can move onto this one more confidently?

Comment: Yes, that second map you provide is certainly not linear.  The $+4$ is the part that goes wrong.

Comment: Ok thank God because that is exactly what I got and now I know I am doing these right. Thanks so much. How do I show that you helped me on here? I am a noob here sorry,

Comment: You can click the checkmark left of my answer if you like.  That'll show my answer helped you the most and we'll both get "rep" (reputation points) from it.

Comment: idk how to PM you here, but can I ask you another question? I am currently stuck on a R3 to R2 problem and idk what to do.

Comment: You can't PM people here.  Just ask it as a new question.

Comment: Hey I am not sure if you are still here, but can I check my answer with you?

Answer (score 1):

Let $x = (x_1,x_2,x_3)$ and $y = (y_1,y_2,y_3)$ and $p $ in $ R$, then  $T(x+p*y) = (x_1+p*y_1,x_2+p*y_2,-(x_3+p*y_3)) = (x_1+p*y_1,x_2+p*y_2,-x_3 -p*y_3) = (x_1,x_2,-x_3) + (p*y_1,p*y_2,-p*y_3) = T(x) + p*T(y)$

Answer (score 0):

You just need to verify the condition $T(aX+by)=aT(X)+bT(Y)$ where $X,Y\in\mathbb R^3$ and $a,b$ are scalars in $\mathbb R$.